# Selector method called in wrong class

Tags: objective-c, selector

I'm trying to make my code "easier" to use. I got a class (called 'Functions') with a couple of static functions. One of these functions creates a UIRefreshControl and returns it.

```
+(UIRefreshControl*)createRefreshControlWithColor:(UIColor*) color andFunction:(SEL)selector{
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    return refreshControl;
}
```

Now the refresh controller needs a selector, which give as a parameter.

From my tableViewController (NewsViewController) I now call

```
UIRefreshControl* refreshControl = [UIFunctions createRefreshControlWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] andFunction:@selector(getNews)];
```

Where getNews is a function in NewsViewController.

When I run this code, it tells me that there is no function "getNews" in "Functions.h". Apparantly (and maybe logically) it looks in 'function' instead of in 'NewsViewController'

Is it possible (and if so, how?) to do this via this way?

Comment: Change your code this way:


That would indeed solve this problem. But on a more abstract view, would this be possible?

Comment: You cannot pass function name like that. You are missing the concepts of basic OOP. An object of a class calls a function, how can a static method call function of some other class? Create a object of refreshControl , set target as self and add action there. Alternatively you can add notification object passing the function to be called.

Comment: Apparantly the target parameter i pass to the refreshcontrol is the Class it will look in for the function. I'm now passing the newsViewController to the function as well and then passing it as the target. It now works ;)